# Transcribe and channel:forms

Tags: safecracker, transcribe

I've upgraded EE to **2.9.2** and have found some strange behaviour with Transcribe.  The problem is that some channel entries did not have a language set in the **exp_transcribe_entries_languages** table.  This was not a big problem because I could just run a script to fix the issue.

However, I have found that entries created via channel:forms do not even get an entry in the exp_transcribe_entries_languages table which means that these entries will not get displayed to the user.

e.g. A member entering a delivery address.  This address is stored but no record is created in the exp_transcribe_entries_languages table so that address will never be of use.  There must always be a valid language_id mapped to each channel entry for it to be displayed correctly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried parsing the language_id in a hidden field?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jelle Dijkstra. I tried adding this: <input type="hidden" name="language_id" value="1"/> hard coding the correct language id but this has no effect.  I've emailed eeHarbor, they sent me an new version but no luck there either.

Comment: Same issue here.
When I edit an entry by channel form it save the entry without his language. But if I add transcribe='disable' to my exp:channel:entries tag transcribe use is null. Has anybody found a soludtion to make transcribe work with Channel forms?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use this parameter in your tag pair:

> transcribe="disable"